# Prove that, $a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2≥abc$

Tags: inequality

> If $a+b+c=1.5$
>
> Prove that,
>
> $a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2≥abc$

I know this inequality: $a^2+b^2+c^2≥ab+bc+ac$

But, I don't know, how to use this inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Look my solution:

$(ab-bc+ac)^2+(ac-ab+bc)^2+(bc+ab-ac)^2≥0 \Rightarrow 3 a^2 b^2 - 2 a^2 b c + 3 a^2 c^2 - 2 a b^2 c - 2 a b c^2 + 3 b^2 c^2 ≥0 \Rightarrow 3(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)≥2abc(a+b+c) \Rightarrow a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2≥abc$

Done.

Answer (score 0):

we write $$(ab)^2+(ac)^2+(bc)^2\geq a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2=abc(a+b+c)=\frac{3}{2}abc\geq abc$$
we have used $$x^2+y^2+z^2\geq xy+yz+zx$$